# Adding custom styles to RTE ribbon

Tags: 2013, ribbon, style.css

I want to add some custom styles to the ribbon on my site. I found [This blog post](http://tomislavspadmin.blogspot.com/2014/05/how-to-add-custom-styles-to-ribbon-in.html) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21874519/how-to-add-a-custom-paragraph-style-in-my-sharepoint-2013-blog).

I can't use SharePoint designer like in the tutorial, but I'm doing all the same things by hand. I create a style like this:

```
span.ms-rteElement-SmartPageElement{
 -ms-name:"Smart style";
 color:red;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size:1.5em;
 font-family:Verdana;
}
```

And put it in *~sitecollection/_catalogs/Masterpage/CustomRibbonStyles.css* I went into the master page and added a  tag. Everything is checked in and published.

I see in my browser debugger that the css file is loaded and if I hand edit the source of my rich text column I see the styling. So all that is hooked up and working.

But I'm not seeing the choice in my ribbon.

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: I just noticed that my site is only showing the out of the box Page Elements and none of the out of the box Text Styles. so that might be part of the problem.

Comment: hmm it looks like on custom new/edit forms my styles get messed up. Out of the box new/edit forms it is working.

Comment: Any luck with this? I have the same problem

Comment: I didn't. But I might be working on it again in the future.